# Git status only showing newly created files after becoming root

Tags: macos, git

I have an empty repo and cloned it on my local machine.
Next I have created created some files.

When running `git status` in the terminal (in the project directory), no files show up as user, but when I run it as root they are visible.

I've installed git via the git installer for OSX, installed XCode command line tools, and added git to `$PATH`.

I'm also using the Atlassian SourceTree app.
Same problem, but when I run this app as root, it sees the new files.

Anybody got an idea of what can be the problem?

Best,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not run git as root user, and you should never ever run git as root user on a project which your normally use as normal user.

Running git as root will create files belonging to root (e.g. `.git/index`, ...) which your normal user won't be able to update later.

Solution:

1. run `chown` to restore the correct ownership
2. stop using git as root.

Comment: And what does "correct ownership" mean? I've added the files while being logged in as normal user and git is installed in /usr/local/bin folder. So why does git not see my files, while they do show up with `ls-l`?

Thanks.

Comment: Where git is installed is irrelevant. The correct ownership is that files should belong to your normal user. There's absolutely no reason to have files belonging to root for your day-to-day development.

Comment: Have you checked *all* files? including `.git/`, the files and subfolders it contains?

Comment: I've run `sudo chown -R $UID .git/ `. 
Then `touch test.html` to create new file.
`git status` > nothing.
`su` <entered password>`git status` > untracked files 'test.html'

Comment: Perhaps you have a user-wide ignore file. `git check-ignore -v index.html` is your friend.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks for the hint. Didn't look in that spot for the problem...
I don't know how it got in there, but there was a `*.*` in my .gitignore_global ....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission as user to view the folder files? sounds like the permissions are for root only

`ls -la` in terminal will show you the group and owner. If your user is not in the group or not the owner you will not be able to read the folder content.

#### How to fix?

`sudo chmod 655 .`

#### how to verify the problem?

Open terminal as user and try to list the file content. If you can cant see the files change the group or permissions of the folder so everyone (or whoever you choose) can read/write to this folder.